# foreach loop not executing properly

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

For some reason, my for loop items does not get executed.

```
// Message to the client
$message = "<html><body>";
$message .= "<p>";

foreach($data as $item) {
      $message .= "<b>
      &#10139;<a style='color:#FF6400; text-decoration: none' href='{$item['link']}'>{$item['title']}</a></b><br>";
      $message .= "Format: {$item['format']} <br>";
      $message .= "Cost: &#36;{$item['costs']} <br>";
      $message .= "Estimated Duration: {$item['duration']} hours<br>";
      $message .= "<br>";

    }
```

Below is where `$data` is defined:

```
// Converting the array into individual strings
$formats = implode("','", $formatsArray);
$topics = implode("','", $topicsArray);



// Check to see if user is careless about the format
// Always use prepare statements to store data
if($_POST['costs'] == "any") {
  if(in_array("any",$formatsArray)) {

    $resources = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM resources WHERE
        (format IN ('Video', 'Podcast', 'Blog/Article', 'forum', 'Online Course'))
         AND (topic IN (?))");
    $resources->bind_param('s', $topics);
  }

  // If user has a specific format in mind, then proceed with the following
  else {
    // Prepare the statement
    $resources = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM resources WHERE
            (format IN (?))
             AND (topic IN (?))");

    // Bind the statement
    $resources->bind_param('ss',$formats, $topics);

  }
}

  else if($_POST['costs'] == "free") {
    if(in_array("any",$formatsArray)) {

      // Prepare statement
      $resources = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM resources WHERE
          (format IN ('Video', 'Podcast', 'Blog/Article', 'forum', 'Online Course'))
           AND (topic IN (?))
           AND  cost like 0");

      // Bind paramater
      $resources->bind_param('s', $topics);
    }

  // If user has a specific format in mind, then proceed with the following
    else {

      // Prepare the statement
      $resources = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM resources WHERE
              (format IN (?))
               AND (topic IN (?))
               AND  (cost like 0)");

      // Bind the statement
      $resources->bind_param('ss', $formats, $topics);

    }
}

else if($_POST['costs'] == "100") {
  if(in_array("any",$formatsArray)) {

    // Prepare statement
    $resources = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM resources WHERE
        (format IN ('Video', 'Podcast', 'Blog/Article', 'forum', 'Online Course'))
         AND (topic IN (?))
         AND  (cost <= 100)");

    // Bind paramater
    $resources->bind_param('s', $topics);
  }

  // If user has a specific format in mind, then proceed with the following
  else {

    // Prepare statement
    $resources = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM resources WHERE
            (format IN (?))
             AND (topic IN (?))
             AND  (cost <= 100)");

    // Bind paramater
    $resources->bind_param('ss', $formats, $topics);

  }
}

// Execute the prepare statement
$resources->execute();

    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())

    {
      $data[] = array(
      'format' => $row['format'],
      'title' => $row['title'],
      'costs' => $row['cost'],
      'stage' => $row['stage'],
      'topic' => $row['topic'],
      'duration' => $row['duration'],
      'link' => $row['link']
  );
    }
```

I am certain the query ran successfully because no error was returned, and I do have items stored in it.I have converted my query to using prepared statements instead.

Comment: `while($row=$result->fetch_assoc());` <= `;` end of statement. Plus, there's no error because it's valid syntax.

Comment: What do you wants with the messages? Do you want to "echo" it?

Comment: I agree with @Fred-ii- Theres a semicolon `;` breaking the code.

Comment: thanks. that was a typo, even when the semi column is removed the error persist

Comment: *"because no error was returned"* - Then you're saying *"the error persist"* ^ - being? (Oh, and you're welcome).

Comment: what if you `var_dump($data)` before the `foreach` ?

Comment: also where is `$message` defined? you are using `.=` assuming it is already defined.

Comment: I was about to retract my vote to close and it got closed before I could retract it. Edit: I have voted to reopen. You may also add a bit more code/information to your question.

Comment: alright, if @Fred-ii- says that, I re-open. It's a first for me

Comment: @Drew sorry buddy, I didn't see your name being the last one, I thought it was the other guy's. I edited my comment in regards to that.

Comment: is this yins a good question or not Fred, I don't even read them half the time. Might suggest my scoring

Comment: @Drew Yins? More like "Yang" ;-)

Comment: I moved down to the Amish country. I can't help it. The manure has polluted my brain.

Comment: i will add more details such as var_dumping the data

Comment: the var dump prints out undefined variable $data null

Comment: _I am certain the query ran successfully_ Show the query and the error checking code that you run to prove that the query ran ok. you may be sure but we are not. **Also** show where you put the `var_dump()`

Comment: "*the var dump prints out undefined variable $data null*" You did this after `while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){$data[] = array(...`? Because `foreach` expects an innumerable so the code would result in an error

Comment: ive tried while($row=$result->fetch_array()){ and same thing the only time it worked was when i was not using prepared statements and use mysqli_fetch_array instead

Comment: ive added more info on how the query is being retrieved in my initial post

Comment: Try doing an `echo $topics` just after `$topics = implode("','", $topicsArray);` I think you should be able to see the error from that

Comment: thanks. everything was working fine until i decided to use prepared statements in other words when using mysqli_fetch_array with the while loop it works fine